# ColdFusion 11 server on Linux slowness due to blocked SeedGenerator thread

Tags: performance, coldfusion, coldfusion-11, random-seed

I have installed ColdFusion 11 on a Redhat Linux server. From time to time, I can see some degree of slowness. When it's slow, I can see there is always a blocked SeedGenerator thread waiting. It'd be highly appreciated if someone could provide hints on how to fix the problem. Here are some related data:

- Server: Linux 2.6.32-504.1.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 31 11:37:10 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Physical memory: 6GB
- CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5560  @ 2.80GHz
- java: coldfusion build-in 1.7.0_55-b13
- jvm: -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m  -Dcoldfusion.jsafe.defaultalgo=FIPS186Random

I also enabled the JMXremote. And JConsole indicates that the peak heap memory usage is 700MB and peak permgen is 120MB. Linux top command indicates high CPU usage and Jconsole shows a SeedGenerator Thread uses 99% CPU from time to time.

I checked the OS random number pool and /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail has at least 120 all the time (most of the time the number is between 120 to 190). I even use rngd to bump up the available random bits but it doesn't help. I also removed /dev/random and linked /dev/urandom to it without any improvement.

The stack trace for the SeedGenerator thread is:

```
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)  
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)  
sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$ThreadedSeedGenerator.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: When we experience "slowness", it's almost always due to inefficient code being executed.  Check your http logs to see what was running at the time.

Comment: The application was deployed on CF9(with jrun) without any performance problem. The same application now is also deployed on Windows8 (CF11 with tomcat) with the bundled jre with the same jvm arguments as the linux deployment without problem. The observed slowness always happens when the SeedGenerator thread is blocked. I am not sure how much random bit  FIPS186Random requires. Maybe the 120 random bits in /dev/random is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After banging my head for a day, I eventually came up with a temporary solution which improved the performance a lot. Adding "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom" to the jvm will instruct the Tomcat to use /dev/urandom instead of the default /dev/random. Please note that the non-blocking /dev/urandom is less secure than /dev/random. If you really want high security for SSL/SSH or so, you need to beef the system up with some random number generation hardware.

For more troubleshooting notes, please see the [here](https://liuzy163.wordpress.com/2015/03/20/tomcat-server-slow-due-to-blocked-seedgenerator-thread-on-insufficient-random-number-on-linux/).